# A bit of an explanation on the array_diff_uassoc function in php

Tags: php

Sorry for another noob question, but... Can someone please explain to me what the function myfunction is actually doing. I understand it's checking if the variables $a and $b are identical and than it's suppose to return 0 if they're identical but the next return is confusing. I see their using the ternary operators.

```
function myfunction($a,$b)
{
if ($a===$b)
  {
  return 0;
  }
  return ($a>$b)?1:-1;
}

$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue");
$a2=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","d"=>"blue");
$a3=array("e"=>"yellow","a"=>"red","d"=>"blue");

$result=array_diff_uassoc($a1,$a2,$a3,"myfunction");
print_r($result);
```

the print_r returns

```
Array ( [c] => blue )
```

but how did we get here...

Comment: RTFM mate: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-uassoc.php - it's there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look and review. I guess the only part i'm confused on is the return ($a>$b) ? 1: -1;

Comment: look for ternary operator to find out what is this `(condition) ? a : b;` thing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation of [array_diff_uassoc](https://www.php.net/array_diff_uassoc), it returns the entries from first argument that are unique compared to other arguments. And the last argument is the name of the function it uses to check whether item is unique or not.

So because only $a1 contains `'c'=>'blue'` it is returned.

Comment: "e"=>"yellow" is unique as well. Thanks for the explanation and maybe you can explain the $a3 too.

Comment: As stated in the documentation "Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays." So only unique entries in the first argument are returned.

Comment: awwee. great, i'm not sure how i missed that. Thanks.

Comment: What is the use of the user defined function "myfunction" . What will it do ?